# Site Owner \ Site members managed property has no Crawled Properties

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search-results, search-scope

Anyone have a solution for getting the site owner details in search?

Also why the Site Owner and Site members managed property has no Crawled Properties associated with it.